# Searching the database for a keyword with php but only can search for the name

Tags: php, mysql, search

This is my search button on my main file:

```
<form action="search_keyword.php"><br>
  Please enter a key word to search for:<br>
  <input type="text" name="keyword"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
```

I am trying to search a database for keywords like Name e.g Peter and role e.g Student, however i can only search for the names:

```
<?php

include "db_conect.php";
$keywordfromform = $_GET["keyword"];


//search the database
echo "<h2>Show all results for:  $keywordfromform</h2>";

$sql = "SELECT ID, Name ,Role, Responsibilities, Age, Date_of_birth, Email FROM person WHERE Name LIKE '%" . $keywordfromform  . "%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo  "ID: ". $row["ID"]. " - " . $row["Name"]. ", " . $row["Role"]. ". " . $row["Responsibilities"]. " (Age-" . $row["Age"]. " Date of birth -" . $row["Date_of_birth"]. ") Email: ". $row["Email"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
<a href="connect.php">Return to main page</a>
```

Comment: Why can you only search Name? Use the WHERE clause on another field.

Comment: add another clause

Comment: Also note that the code tags icon is two curly braces {}

Comment: Please consider properly escaping your query to avoid having some nefarious actor wiping out your entire database.

Comment: Refs: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html - and do it yourself. No better way than "learning". Also use a prepared statement, if you value your work and your database ;-)

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Name ,Role, Responsibilities, Age, Date_of_birth, Email FROM person WHERE Name LIKE '%" . $keywordfromform  . "%' OR Role LIKE '%" .$keywordfromform  . "%'";
```

This way you will be searching for Name and Role.

I also sugest you to adding method="POST" to your form so you can send values in a more secure way. That would imply you changing the $_GET["keyword"] on your PHP to $_POST["keyword"];